# Ubuntu 13.04 Terminal closes when minimized

Tags: 13.04, gnome-terminal, minimize

My terminal window closes when minimized or when I maximize other program window. This is not useful when coping and pasting commands lines...

Also the terminal window do not appear in the launch bar when actived

What's happening?

Comment: Did you get this working?  I have the same issue.

Comment: It is working now. The OS was a fresh install and got working after a restart

Answer (score 1):

You must click the search button in the execution bar, type "terminal", then you click and hold, drag to the bar of execution, after that begin to function normally. Greetings.

Answer (score -1):

Press `Super` Key hold and press `W`. You will see your all running applications. 
Super key means start key on your keyboard. 
Thanks