# No Terminal Icons on Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: unity, 13.04

When I start a Gnome Terminal session in Ubuntu 13.04, there is no terminal icon on the launcher, and when I <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd> through the apps, it is not there either.

Anyone know how I can make this work?

Comment: Have you tried running in the terminal "unity-reset"?

Comment: ERROR: the reset option is now deprecated

Comment: Have you tried this? http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/04/how-to-reset-unity-compiz-in-ubuntu-12-10-and-13-04

Comment: Do you get an icon image with question mark on it?

Answer (score 1):

1. Open a Terminal: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.
2. Now the Terminal should appear on launcher. Right click on it and select "*Block on launcher*".

Answer (score 0):

you can check the home button and search for terminal or console or similar name for your terminal.
or you can update if may be your installation is not done properly
try to update your UBUNTU

Comment: I undestand all of that, but when I have a terminal running on the desktop, there is not triangular symbol on the launcher for each terminal session that I have running.  And I cannot alt-tab through them on the list, because they don't appear.  I hardly think re-installing is the answer.

Comment: See this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/287469/ubuntu-13-04-terminal-closes-when-minimized

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The terminal still running, if you minimize everything you'll see it on desktop but it's not on the left bar. So i tried this, open the shell type Terminal click and drag it to the left bar(sorry for bad english)